# How to add options for select tag from java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form with some drop-downs. I need to have options for select tag dynamically changes according to the id value.

for example if id is 1
 select tag options should be cat,dog
if id=2
select tag options should be apple,banana

I will get id's dynamically from javascript function.

```
   <% @options = Test.function1(@id) %>
```

now i need to append this options for select_tag. If i use this @option directly in form it is giving different output.
After analyzing if i could add options for select from javascript my problem is solved.
Due to some issues i couldn't post complete details.
Updated:

```
      <% @options.each_with_index do|x,i|%>
            var opt = document.createElement('option');
            opt.value = '<%=i%>';
            opt.innerHTML = '<%= x%>';
            select.appendChild(opt);
      <% end %>
```

I used above code in javascript to append @options to select tag but it is not appending

I have used the same code for appending this options for HTML select tag that worked fine but when i use the same code rails it is not appending.

Comment: Please explain the overall aim/problem as this looks a like an XY question.

Comment: In javascript i have called a model function to get options now i need to add those options to select tag. From above code i get option in @options variable now how can i append that to select tag options in rails

Comment: I think its better to use [collection_select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select) for fetching dynamic data from database.

Comment: I think you should use an extra attr in select tag like data-category and store all the options in an array in js variable and sort that array according your selection and add that array to the select.

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript**

```
$('#dropdown1').change ->
      url = '/some/fetch_values';
      value1 = $(this).val()

      if value1 is ""
        $("#dropdwon2").empty()
        $("#dropdwon2").append $("<option></option>").attr("value", '').text('Choose dropdwon2')
      else
        $.post url, {id: dropdown1_id}, ((res) ->

          $("#dropdwon2").empty();
          $("#dropdwon2").append $("<option></option>").attr("value", '').text('Choose a sub-subcategory')
          if res.length > 0
            $.each res, (key, value) ->
              $("#dropdwon2").append $("<option></option>").attr("value", value[0]).text(value[1])

          else
            $('#dropdwon2').empty();

        ), 'JSON'
```

**Controller**

```
def fetch_values

@dropdown2_values = {}  #find values from params[:id]
respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render :json => @dropdown2_values}
    end
end
```

Try this code ..